# GraphX - Weighted shortest path implementation - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Edit - I discovered that the book was written for scala `1.6` but the remainder is `2.11`.

I am trying to implement a weighted shortest path algorithm from Michael Malak and Robin East's `Spark GraphX in Action` book. The part in question is Listing 6.4 "Executing the shortest path algorithm that uses breadcrumbs"  from Chapter 6 [here](https://www.manning.com/books/spark-graphx-in-action#downloads).

I have my own graph that I create from two RDDs. There are `344436` vertices and `772983` edges. I can perform an unweighted shortest path computation using the native GraphX library and I'm confident in the graph construction.

In this case I use their Dijkstra's implementation as follows:

```
val my_graph: Graph[(Long),Double] = Graph.apply(verticesRDD, edgesRDD).cache()

def dijkstra[VD](g:Graph[VD,Double], origin:VertexId) = {
  var g2 = g.mapVertices(
      (vid,vd) => (false, if (vid == origin) 0 else Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())
  )

  for (i <- 1L to g.vertices.count-1) {
    val currentVertexId = g2.vertices
      .filter(!_._2._1)
      .fold((0L, (false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())))(
          (a,b) => if (a._2._2 < b._2._2) a else b)
      )
      ._1

    val newDistances = g2.aggregateMessages[(Double, List[VertexId])](
        ctx => if (ctx.srcId == currentVertexId) {
          ctx.sendToDst((ctx.srcAttr._2 + ctx.attr, ctx.srcAttr._3 :+ ctx.srcId))
        },
        (a,b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b
    )

    g2 = g2.outerJoinVertices(newDistances)((vid, vd, newSum) => {
      val newSumVal = newSum.getOrElse((Double.MaxValue,List[VertexId]()))

      (
          vd._1 || vid == currentVertexId,
          math.min(vd._2, newSumVal._1),
          if (vd._2 < newSumVal._1) vd._3 else newSumVal._2
      )
    })

  }

  g.outerJoinVertices(g2.vertices)((vid, vd, dist) =>
    (vd, dist.getOrElse((false,Double.MaxValue,List[VertexId]()))
      .productIterator.toList.tail
  ))
}

//  Path Finding - random node from which to find all paths
val v1 = 4000000028222916L
```

I then call their function with my graph and a random vertex ID. Previously I had issues with `v1` not being recognised as `long` type and the `L` suffix solved this.

```
val results = dijkstra(my_graph, 1L).vertices.map(_._2).collect

println(results)
```

However, this returns the following:

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
    at GraphX$.dijkstra$1(GraphX.scala:51)
    at GraphX$.main(GraphX.scala:85)
    at GraphX.main(GraphX.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Line 51 refers to the line `var g2 = g.mapVertices(`
Line 85 refers to the line `val results = dijkstra(my_graph, 1L).vertices.map(_._2).collect`

What method is this exception referring to? I am able to package with `sbt` without error and I canno see what method I am calling whcih does not exist.

Comment: Scala 1.6 ? Not possible.

Comment: Hey @eliasah. I asked the author and he said "I have discovered that this dijkstra's function was written for scala 1.6. The remainder of my code is 2.11."

Comment: I think that he mean Spark 1.6. Scala 1.6 doesn't exist

Comment: Ah. I see the transition was made from 1.6 to 2. this summer

Comment: Exactly and what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: I am using 1.6.1. So, it seems I should move to 2.1 and find out what specifically in this piece needs adjusted from 1.6 to 2. Although, if this function was written for 1.6 and it won't run on 1.6 -  that is confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126900/discussion-between-eliasah-and-learningslowly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue wasn't in a version error nor a missing implementation but a misleading error from the compiler.

Ok so here is the thing: After investigating the code, I have noticed that the following section contained one extra closing parentheses :

```
val currentVertexId: VertexId = g2.vertices.filter(!_._2._1)
  .fold((0L, (false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())))(
    (a, b) => if (a._2._2 < b._2._2) a else b))._1 
                                              ^
                                              |
```

You'll just need to remove that extra parentheses and it will work perfectly. Here is the full code :

```
// scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.graphx._
def dijkstra[VD](g: Graph[VD, Double], origin: VertexId) = {
  var g2 = g.mapVertices(
(vid, vd) => (false, if (vid == origin) 0 else Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())
  )

  for (i <- 1L to g.vertices.count - 1) {
    val currentVertexId: VertexId = g2.vertices.filter(!_._2._1)
      .fold((0L, (false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())))(
        (a, b) => if (a._2._2 < b._2._2) a else b)._1

    val newDistances: VertexRDD[(Double, List[VertexId])] =
      g2.aggregateMessages[(Double, List[VertexId])](
    ctx => if (ctx.srcId == currentVertexId) {
      ctx.sendToDst((ctx.srcAttr._2 + ctx.attr, ctx.srcAttr._3 :+ ctx.srcId))
    },
    (a, b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b
  )

g2 = g2.outerJoinVertices(newDistances)((vid, vd, newSum) => {
  val newSumVal = newSum.getOrElse((Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]()))
  (
    vd._1 || vid == currentVertexId,
    math.min(vd._2, newSumVal._1),
    if (vd._2 < newSumVal._1) vd._3 else newSumVal._2
    )
})
}

  g.outerJoinVertices(g2.vertices)((vid, vd, dist) =>
(vd, dist.getOrElse((false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]()))
  .productIterator.toList.tail
  ))
}

//  Path Finding - random node from which to find all paths
```

Now, let's test it :

```
val myVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = sc.makeRDD(Array((1L, "A"), (2L, "B"), (3L, "C"), (4L, "D"), (5L, "E"), (6L, "F"), (7L, "G")))
val myEdges: RDD[Edge[Double]] = sc.makeRDD(Array(Edge(1L, 2L, 7.0), Edge(1L, 4L, 5.0), Edge(2L, 3L, 8.0), Edge(2L, 4L, 9.0), Edge(2L, 5L, 7.0), Edge(3L, 5L, 5.0), Edge(4L, 5L, 15.0), Edge(4L, 6L, 6.0),Edge(5L, 6L, 8.0), Edge(5L, 7L, 9.0), Edge(6L, 7L, 11.0)))

val my_graph = Graph(myVertices, myEdges).cache()

val v1 = 4000000028222916L

val results = dijkstra(my_graph, 1L).vertices.map(_._2).collect

// [CTRL-D]
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
// [Lscala.Tuple2;@668a0785                                                        
// import org.apache.spark.graphx._
// myVertices: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[556] at makeRDD at <console>:37
// myEdges: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Double]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[557] at makeRDD at <console>:39
// my_graph: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[String,Double] = org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl@49ea0d90
// dijkstra: [VD](g: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[VD,Double], origin: org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId)org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[(VD, List[Any]),Double]
// v1: Long = 4000000028222916
// results: Array[(String, List[Any])] = Array((A,List(0.0, List())), (B,List(7.0, List(1))), (C,List(15.0, Li...
scala> results.foreach(println)
// (A,List(0.0, List()))
// (B,List(7.0, List(1)))
// (C,List(15.0, List(1, 2)))
// (D,List(5.0, List(1)))
// (E,List(14.0, List(1, 2)))
// (F,List(11.0, List(1, 4)))
// (G,List(22.0, List(1, 4, 6)))
```

Comment: Oh great. You have done a better debugging job. @eliasah

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't easy to find it. I just know Spark well.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me something @Aroon ?

Comment: @Aroon You are asking me to solve your question ? I'll try to take a look at it when I have some time.

Comment: @Aroon but it's marked as solved. So I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

### Error Analysis:

Please look at the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create
```

Your program is looking for `create()` method, but not getting this.

### Root Cause Analysis:

Actually this type of error is happening when version is mismatched between scala and spark.

**or,**

Compile is done by a version and in runtime it is using another scala version.

---

**Scala Version Difference:**

If you check, **Scala version 2.10.x**

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ObjectRef.java

you will get, `ObjectRef` class have

```
public T elem;
public ObjectRef(T elem) { this.elem = elem; }
public String toString() { return String.valueOf(elem); }
```

---

But if you check, **Scala version 2.11.x**
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ObjectRef.java

you will get, `ObjectRef` class have

```
public T elem;
public ObjectRef(T elem) { this.elem = elem; }
@Override
public String toString() { return String.valueOf(elem); }

public static <U> ObjectRef<U> create(U e) { return new ObjectRef<U>(e); } // Your program wants to get this method, but not getting this.
public static ObjectRef<Object> zero() { return new ObjectRef<Object>(null); }
```

`create()` method is available here.

---

### Solution#1:

So Please confirm that, compile and runtime they are getting from same version of Scala.

### Solution#2:

Please check: [NoSuchMethodError for Scala Seq line in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35465921/2293534)

Here, [Robert Horvick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95076/robert-horvick) also told in this comment like that

> Spark 1.6 is based on Scala 2.10 not 2.11

So you can update Spark version from here http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

**Latest stable version** is Apache Spark 2.0.1, released on Oct 3, 2016

Comment: Thanks for the effort SkyWalker!